# send audio file to phone via sms using twilio.api

Tags: php, twilio

I'm using twilio as for sending sms usnig php

how would i send audio file to phone via sms using twilio.api

Comment: That would mean sending an MMS and Twillio does not support it.  [Twillio FAQ](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-send-or-receive-mms-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check Twillio forums first.  They have the [answer posted here](http://forum.twilio.com/twilio/topics/can_we_sent_audio_files_via_sms_using_twilio_api?from_gsfn=true). They do not support MMS so you cannot send audio via SMS on their platform.

Comment: (Twilio employee here) - Correct, you can't send MMS but you can send a link and let the smartphone itself handle it.